# Pip packages are installed but not working

Tags: pip

I'm new to ubuntu and I've installed many packages via pip but they don't work and give me this error.

> zsh: command not found: ipython

I have tried many ways, but after logout and login, I get the same error until I enter `source ~/.profile`, and then it works correctly.

> ~/.profile

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

I also added `export PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH` to the end of the `.profile` file in the home directory and edited `/etc/skel/.profile` it didn't help me too.

any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Does this help? https://superuser.com/questions/187639/zsh-not-hitting-profile

Comment: Thanks, @dariofac but I don't think so.